# flickering/repainting issue on AWT_SWT frame

Tags: java, swing, eclipse-plugin, awt

I am using AWT_SWT frame bridge to embed a graphical API to eclipse plugin application. All works good but i am facing flickering/repainting issue on moving or scrolling frame. I did lots of R&D, tried some solution like `System.setProperty("sun.awt.noerasebackground", "true"); or`component.setDoubleBuffered(true);` or use of panel or without JPanel or use of JComponent but all didn't work for me. Here is a sample of my code

```
// main composite
    Composite mainComposite = new Composite(GraphicalViewPart._parent, SWT.EMBEDDED | SWT.NO_BACKGROUND);
    System.setProperty("sun.awt.noerasebackground", "true");
    // System.setProperty("sun.awt.noerasebackground", "true");
    GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout();
    gridLayout.numColumns = 1;
    mainComposite.setLayout(gridLayout);
    mainComposite.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH));

    // main frame
    awtframe = SWT_AWT.new_Frame(mainComposite);

    // panel in frame
    /*
    java.awt.Panel awtpanel = new java.awt.Panel(new BorderLayout()) {
        public void update(java.awt.Graphics g) {
            // Do not erase the background 
            paint(g);
        }
    };
    */
    JComponent component=new JComponent() {
    };
    component.setDoubleBuffered(true);
    awtframe.setLayout(new java.awt.GridLayout());
    awtframe.add(component);
```

Please help me to find any solution of it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As described in the eclipse corner article [Swing/SWT Integration](https://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Swing-SWT-Integration/index.html) section "Creating a Root Pane Container", you have to set a heavyweight component as first child of the frame. And only `JApplet` is possible:

```
Composite composite = new Composite(parent, SWT.EMBEDDED | SWT.NO_BACKGROUND);
Frame frame = SWT_AWT.new_Frame(composite);
JApplet applet = new JApplet();

applet.add(myComponent); //add your component here

frame.add(applet);
```

In my case this solution solved all issues, including the flickering during resizing.

Running with SWT 3.4 and Java SE 1.7.